# How to halve any given pentagon ABCDE with a line segment AX

Tags: geometry

Let there be a random pentagon ABCDE. Draw a straight like AX, so that:

- X lays on one of the pentagon's sides,
- AX halves the pentagon into two parts of equal area

How can this be done?

Comment: What are you looking for? A formula in terms of the coordinates? A geometrical construction?

Comment: @almagest Maybe the OP is looking for a way to place X on the pentagon circumference **"with only straight edge and compass"**

Comment: Strange, Rudolf, that you came back to edit your question, but didn't engage with the comments that have been made, to clarify just what exactly you're after.

Comment: See also http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44827/half-the-pentagon

Comment: @GerryMyerson I had first asked this here, but didn't word my question well, so I didn't get answers. I later asked it on Puzzling.SE, and got an answer, so I decided to come back and reword the question here.

Comment: When what you should have done, Rudolf, was 1) edit the question here so that people could understand it and maybe give you an answer, and 2) when you got an answer at puzzling, you should have come back here to post a link to it. Disgusting.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understand your arguments and took them to thought. I'd like to say that when I first asked this, my knowledge of English was a fraction of what it was now (hence no answers caused by bad wording), and I had completely forgotten that I posted this here. Now, I came across this and edited; I didn't answer for a single reason: let somebody else write an answer - after all, it's a easy question, no hard maths, and a chance for some user to post something. I'm not going after rep here, on SE. If you would have any other thing to say to me, please contact me through chat, not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a line passing through $B$ parallel to $AC$. Let it intersect
the line $CD$ at $F$. We have
$$\verb/Area/(ABC) = \verb/Area/(AFC)$$

Construct a line passing through $E$ parallel to $AD$. Let it intersect
the line $CD$ at $G$. We have
$$\verb/Area/(AED) = \verb/Area/(AGD)$$

Let $H$ be the mid-point of $FG$. If $H$ lies on the segment $CD$, then
$$\verb/Area/(ABCH) = \verb/Area/(AFH) = \verb/Area/(AHG) = \verb/Area/(AHDE)$$
and we can take $H$ to be $X$.

Otherwise, $H$ lies outside segment $CD$. 
Let's say $H$ lies inside the segment $GD$ as shown in diagram below.

[image: How to bisect a pentagon]

Construct a line passing through $F$ parallel to $AD$. Let it intersect
the line $DE$ at $I$. Let $X$ be the mid-point of $EI$, we have

$$\verb/Area/(ABCDX) = \verb/Area/(AFDX) = \verb/Area/(AIX) = \verb/Area/(AXE)$$

So this $X$ is indeed the point that bisect the pentagon in equal area.
The case $H$ lies inside the segment $FC$ can be handled  in a similar manner.